# The AppStore is temporarily unavailable. Please try again

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

This is very frustrating. We are not able to download apps from App Store, as we keep getting error message "The AppStore is temporarrily unavailable. Please try again". I falied also to login to App Store.

I log in to Member Center, but fail to login to "iTunes Connect-Submit and manage your apps on the App Store."

It it app store which has issue or it is the app.

Comment: Take a look here http://thenextweb.com/apple/2015/03/11/the-apple-app-store-is-having-problems-and-itunes-connect-is-down/

Comment: App Store is back online.

Comment: @IconDaemon Both app stores  still down at 1536 GMT

Comment: Well, it's working in the NE US. Perhaps its an Akamai problem.

Comment: And it's down again.

Comment: plist parsing error now, instead of STATUS_CODE_ERROR Overall… no improvement as yet ;)

Answer (score 3):

There is a major (worldwide and lasting more than an hour) disruption with all the App Stores showing as down on Apple's status page. For future reference, it was clear there were issues with the store for more than an hour before the status page showed that outage.

[image]

The good news is that the history is backdated showing when the issues started and also that some of the outages have been resolved already.

[image]

Support links are at:

- https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/
- https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 1):

My guess right now is it's not just you.

I'm getting STATUS_CODE_ERROR & an eternally spinning login…

… as are all these people - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6868907

Google gives a lot of news hits for "[app store down](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=app%20store%20down&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=app%20store%20down&safe=off&rls=en&tbm=nws)"

Doesn't seem to be affecting iOS 8.2 downloads - mine is coming through just fine right now. Thought that may have been related, but appears not.

Update 17:30 GMT - Apple Service Status now shows App Store as down - https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

Update 18:45 - source [The Telegraph](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/technology/apple/11465044/Apples-App-Store-and-iTunes-go-down.html)

> The problems are estimated to be costing Apple more than $4m (£2.7m) in lost sales from iTunes and the App Store. With these systems down, users are unable to buy new apps or install updates to ones that they already own. They will also be unable to buy music or videos from iTunes.
>   Apple has apologised for the problems. In a statement, it said: "We are apologise to our customers experiencing problems with iTunes and other services this morning. The cause was an internal DNS error at Apple.
>   "We're working to make all of the services available to customers as soon as possible, and we thank everyone for their patience."

Answer (score 0):

The App Store is unavailable for me in the US. No indication at the [Apple System Status Page](https://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/) that there is a problem.

Comment: There is if you try to report one - you can't get through :(

Comment: They now fixed that bit… just the rest we have to worry about ;)